# How to store random alphabets in a 2d array in pairs?

Tags: c, arrays

I am making a game in **c** which requires a **2D array** of size **m*n** which needs to store alphabets in pairs. It's a memory game where user needs to select 2 slots from the **matrix** which is hidden. If they both match then they are deleted from the **matrix**.

for example: for array a[3][4] it should store

```
a t x e
b a t n 
x b n e
```

Comment: What is the question? Is it about allocating memory OR generating random characters? Please specify.

Comment: generating random characters and storing them

Comment: Check how to generate random numbers in C - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html

Comment: it needs to store **alphabets** and not numbers

Comment: Just map 0 to a, 1 to b, 2 to c ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am sharing the code, please try and type the code yourself. I am giving some steps with this answer, which should help you think through the code if you want to implement it all by yourself.

Here are some steps.

1) Input `m` and `n`

```
int m, n;
scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
```

2) Allocate memory to the array

```
char *arr[m];
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    arr[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(char));
}
```

3) Now, since you mentioned in one of your comments, the program should generate **random alphabets and not numbers**, let me tell you, C allows casting of datatype from `int` to `char`. Here is how you will generate random characters.

```
for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        c = (char) (rand() % 26) + 'a'; // Generate a random character between 'a' and 'z'
        arr[i][j] = c;
    }
}
```

Here is the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int m, n, i, j;
    char c;
    scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);

    char *arr[m];
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        arr[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(char));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            c = (char) (rand() % 26) + 'a'; // Generate a random character between 'a' and 'z'
            arr[i][j] = c;
            printf("%c ", c);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

**Input:**

```
3
4
```

**Output:**

```
n w l r 
b b m q 
b h c d
```

I think this is the expected output!

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to generate pairs of random numbers, the logic is easy. Generate (m * n) / 2 random numbers and duplicate them in an array, with (m * n) elements in total. Now, insert these elements into random locations in the 2d array!

Comment: You should check the return value from `scanf`

Comment: Also in C you should not cast the return value from `malloc` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @EdHeal, I have removed the cast from malloc. Can you please be more specific on how to check the return value of scanf?

Comment: Read the manual page for `scanf` - https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf - Returns number matched